# SharePoint Online Filter By URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, search, sharepoint-rest-api, filter

I am working with the SharePoint API and trying to filter search results based on specific URLs.

Currently, I have the following search query:

```
http://www.test.com/_api/search/query?querytext=%27Hello%27&trimduplicates=false&sortlist=%27Write:descending%27&rowlimit=5000
```

I want to filter the results from the API based on the following URLs:
For eg I would want to return all results with https://www.test.com/SiteTest only. So on and so forth..

https://www.test.com/SiteTest

https://www.test.com/Divisions/Academy/Test.pdf

https://www.test.com/Divisions/National/File.doc

The url above are located within the cells..

```
queryResultArray[i].Cells.results[6].Value
```

Is there a specific filter or URL parameter that I can use in the SharePoint API to achieve this? I appreciate any guidance or examples on how to implement this filtering logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `Path` property for filtering SharePoint search results from specific sites.

For example, try this:

```
http://www.test.com/_api/search/query?querytext='Hello AND Path:https://www.test.com/SiteTest'&trimduplicates=false&sortlist='Write:descending'&rowlimit=5000
```

**Reference**: [SharePoint REST - How to search a specific SharePoint site? API calls returning results from all sites I have access to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77680290/sharepoint-rest-how-to-search-a-specific-sharepoint-site-api-calls-returning/77689585#77689585)

Check this for using multiple `Path` values: [SharePoint REST Query with multiple variable for a query tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697540/sharepoint-rest-query-with-multiple-variable-for-a-query-tag)

Comment: Thank you sir. It is working correctly now :)

Comment: You're welcome, I am glad it worked for you. Keep using this platform for asking any questions related to SharePoint.