# Graph Search Query by SiteId

Tags: microsoft-graph, graph-api

I am trying to do a graph search query
that bring the last 20 items updated from a specific site ordered by the lastModifiedDateTime, and if possible also filtered by a custom field that they should have.

this is the query i have

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query
    {
        "Requests": [
            {
                "entityTypes": [
                    "listItem"
                ],
                "query": {
                    "queryString": "isDocument:true AND siteId:<site-id> "
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

in this example the when i try to add the siteid the query breaks and brings no result

Comment: Do you have site URL with you? If yes, you can try using `Path` as well. Check this: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/310922/sharepoint-online-filter-by-url/310923#310923 and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: i do, i was working with path but i had to do a go around to get it with the site id, so i was looking to do it by using the site id

Comment: So, using `Path` will work for you or not?